# pyspark join on hierarchy iteratively

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With the following dataframe:

```
data1  = [("A",None, 1, 'Highest'),("B","A", 2, 'Medium'),("C","B", 3, 'Lowest'),("D","B", 3, 'Lowest')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = ['ID','ParentID','Hierarchy','HierarchyName'])
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

How can I produce this dataframe in PySpark instead, so that every record has a hierarchy tree from its level all the way up to the highest level (where ParentID is null).  But bearing in mind that that a tree could contain any number of nodes, i.e. 3 might not be the lowest hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: This is a graph problem, are you willing to solve it with spark SQL only ? GraphX module of apache spark is more suitable for this kind of problems

Comment: yeah because that means it can be done in databricks right?  if so then yes it doesn't have to be pyspark

Answer (score 0):

This is a graph task you can tackle with spark graphx module, using the pregel api. You will have to use scala spark. See
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html

If you are willing to keep pyspark you can take a look at the graphframes package. The last release is for spark 3.0.x and it might not work with latest spark versions. See https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html